# Closing DB connection with try-with-resources java

Tags: java, database, connection, coding-style, try-with-resources

I have primitive get method for my database. I need to get course by its id and then close connection and statement.

```
public Course get(int id) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        try (Connection connection = ConnectionConfig.getDbConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(GET_COURSE)){
            statement.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet course = statement.executeQuery();
            course.next();
            String result = course.getString(1);
            return new Course(id, result);
        }
    }
```

I want to do it with try-with-resources. Will it work in this code or auto-closing won't work because of return statement in the block? On the other hand, I don't want to use return outside this block because method can return object with null field. What method form is the most effective and readable in this situation? Thank you in advance, I understand this is quite amateurish question)

Comment: connection will be closed

Answer (score 0):

Closing the connections code is usually written in finally block

```
Connection connection = null;
try {
connection = ConnectionConfig.getDbConnection();
//do all the stuff

}
finally{
connection.close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The connection will closed by the try with resources block. The condition for that is that a given class implements AutoCloseable. And that is already the case.

As it can be seen [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html)